# Datatable: add computed column with subtotals

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have generated a datatable by querying a large mysql-database.
This resulted in about 7000 rows. Now I would like to add a column that calculates the sum of column "QUANTITY" for every unique value in column "BREAK2" (like a 'group by').

Example:

```
BREAK2 | QUANTITY | COMPUTED

A          10         30
B          20         40
A          10         30
A          20         30
B          20         40
```

If I use

```
Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
dc.ColumnName = "SumQTY"
dt.Columns.Add(dc)

For Each dr As DataRow In DT.Rows
    dr("SumQTY") = DT.Compute("Sum(QUANTITY)", "BREAK2 = '" & dr("BREAK2") & "'")
Next
```

it takes a long time (several minutes before I break it off).

When I query the same data with a querytool named BRIO, and I add a computed column with formula "Sum(QUANTITY,BREAK2)", it takes about 1 second to get the results.

What could be the difference between these methods?
Why is the VB.net code taking so long?
I have tried to use LINQ but same bad performance.

Thanks.
Nas

Comment: Just an hint: If you have 2000 rows with column BREAK2='A' you call the Compute for 2000 times to obtain the same result.

Comment: You should just use SQL to get that data.  If you wanted to, you could generate a result set with the aggregated values and then join it to the result set you already have.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be pretty fast

```
Sub Main
    Dim sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Dim rnd = new Random()
    Dim dt = new DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("BREAK2", "".GetType())
    dt.Columns.Add("QUANTITY", 0.GetType())
    dt.Columns.Add("COMPUTED", 0.GetType())
    for i = 0 to 7000
        dt.Rows.Add("A", rnd.Next(0, 30))
        dt.Rows.Add("B", rnd.Next(0, 30))
        dt.Rows.Add("C", rnd.Next(0, 30))
        dt.Rows.Add("D", rnd.Next(0, 30))
    Next

    Dim keys As List(Of String) = dt.AsEnumerable() _ 
                                  .Select(Function(x) x("BREAK2").ToString()) _ 
                                  .Distinct().ToList()
    For Each k in keys
        Dim listOfRow = dt.AsEnumerable() _ 
                        .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("BREAK2") = k).ToList()

        Dim total = listOfRow.Sum(Function(t) t.Field(Of Integer)("QUANTITY"))
        For Each row in listOfRow
           row.SetField(Of Integer)("COMPUTED", total)
        Next
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub
```

As I have said in my comment above, it is silly to recalculate the same value for thousands of time.
Using LINQ you could extract the unique values of the column BREAK2, execute the sum just one time for the subset of rows identified by the key and then set the same subset of rows with the total.
On my PC this takes at max 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. In my example it looks like there are only 2 possible values for column "BREAK2", but it's more like there are 6000 different values for BREAK2 in a total of 7000 rows. Sorry if I gave misleading info. I tried your code and it's already running for 2 minutes now..